# Unable to set bitmap from ActivityResult in ImageView [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app the user by clicking on a custom button is able to choose from a modal to load a picture from the gallery or take a picture, once the user done i get the image in my onActivityResult and i would set that picture as a preview instead of the "no image" i set by default.

The issue is that by doing `.setImageBitmap(image)` it set a gray square instead of the taken picture..

My code looks like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1 || requestCode == 2) {
        val image = data?.extras!!["data"] as Bitmap?
        findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView).setImageBitmap(image)
    }
}
```

XML

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_image"
            app:tint= "#909090"
            android:contentDescription="@string/foto" />
```

And here is what i get:

[image]

The code where i create the dialog to get the image is the following:

```
fun takePicture(view: View) {
    val items = arrayOf<CharSequence>("Scatta la foto", "Scegli dalla Galleria", "Annulla")
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Aggiungi la foto")
    builder.setItems(items) { dialog, item ->
        when {
            items[item] == "Scatta la foto" -> {
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
            }
            items[item] == "cegli dalla Galleria" -> {
                val intent = Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                )
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2)
            }
            items[item] == "Annulla" -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
    builder.show()
}
```

Comment: Your `onActivityResult()` handles your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` scenario, but not `ACTION_PICK`. For `ACTION_PICK`, you will get a `Uri` in `data.data`, and you can use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, coil) for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare but is it normal that in `data?.extras?.get("data")` in debug i see the bitmap of the photo i made?

Comment: That is how `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is supposed to work, if you do not include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` to tell the user's chosen camera app where to write the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LOL**

The issue was the **tint** set to grey in ImageView which was showing the icon in the right way but when the picture was taken it was setting the whole picture to the greyish color

So by removing

```
   app:tint= "#909090"
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well in data you are not getting bitmap you are doing it wrong don't expect data to return a bitmap it will return you a URI of that picture you selected you need to get the absolute path from that photo and then load the image from that given absolute path
`filePath = filesManager.getPath(data?.data!!) bindImage(ui.ivProfileImage, filePath, Constants.USER_PLACE_HOLDER)`

Here FileManager class is taking data from onActivitResult and converting it into absolute path afterwards loading image. You can pass that image to glide and load image into your imageview using glide.